# jquery bug on navigation - any suggestions?

Tags: jquery

Can anybody figure out why this code is effecting all my other jquery scripts.
This is a navigation that toogles left to right but when implemented it breaks my other toogles.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var $fee = jQuery.noConflict();
        $fee('.left-nav-links').css({"width":"60px"});
        var already_open = 0;
        $fee(document).on("mouseover",".left-nav-links > li",function(){
            if(already_open==0){
                already_open    =   1;
                $fee('.left-nav-links').stop();
                $fee('.left-nav-links').animate({"width":"192px"}, 1000);
            }
        }).on("mouseout", ".left-nav-links > li",function(){
            if(already_open==1){
                already_open    =   0;
                $fee('.left-nav-links').stop();
                $fee('.left-nav-links').animate({"width":"60px"}, 1000);
            }
        })
        $fee('#setting-popup-btn').click(function() {
            $fee('.dropdown-profile').toggle();
        });
        $fee('#setting-popup-btn2').click(function(){
            $fee('.dropdown-profile').toggle();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Do you have a demo that we may see?

Comment: Line 16 - missing semi-colon?

Comment: Did you put this after your other scripts? Otherwise you are changing your jQuery object to $fee

Comment: Try wrapping the above in $(function(){ });

Answer (score 0):

```
var $fee = jQuery.noConflict();
$fee('.left-nav-links').css({"width":"60px"});
var already_open = 0;
$fee(document).on("mouseover",".left-nav-links > li",function(){
    if(already_open==0){
        already_open    =   1;
        $fee('.left-nav-links').stop();
        $fee('.left-nav-links').animate({"width":"192px"}, 1000);
    }
}).on("mouseout", ".left-nav-links > li",function(){
    if(already_open==1){
        already_open    =   0;
        $fee('.left-nav-links').stop();
        $fee('.left-nav-links').animate({"width":"60px"}, 1000);
    }
}) // missing semi-colon HERE
$fee('#setting-popup-btn').click(function() {
    $fee('.dropdown-profile').toggle();
});
$fee('#setting-popup-btn2').click(function(){
    $fee('.dropdown-profile').toggle();
});
```